# Is it possible to compress video on Android?

Tags: android, video, compression

I want to do video compression.

Actually in my application I want to have two options, one is low and another is high. If I choose the low option then the application will compress the video and then upload it. If I choose high then it will upload the original video which I have recorded itself.

I want to do this thing in my application and I'm confused. I have searched google a lot but I'm not able to find the useful way to solve this question please if anyone can help me out.

Comment: To compress a video, you will need to re-encode it to a lower bit-rate or maybe a lower resolution. You can search the Google to find many libraries available to encode videos in Java. I would suggest you to try ffmpeg. Here's a [link](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php) to get you started. And here's an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515967/encode-video-using-ffmpeg-from-javacv-on-android-causes-native-code-crash) that might help your cause.

Comment: I M still not getting the solution....

Comment: Did you try the codes on the link's that I have provided? If you want someone to provide you with code that you can copy paste,then please don't expect that.

Comment: you provided me the good help i m not telling that i want to code to copy paste i m not at all expecting that thing i m still working on this stuff i will get back to you thanks

Comment: Hello i just want to ask you that do i need only one ffmpeg-java Jar ??

Comment: Probably yes, that would do.

Comment: The library given in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23815402/4153725 is free.

Answer (score 13):

I used [ffmpeg4android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netcompss_dev2.ffmpeg_android2),

And was able to achieve this in about 10min using only java,
Note that its a commercial library.

Comment: How to use it in code ??

Comment: See detailed explanations here: http://androidwarzone.blogspot.co.il/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html

Comment: I like to use the ffmpeg4android , Do i need to register or pay something for that . What are the license details?.

Comment: Licensing information: ffmpeg4android.netcompss.com

Comment: @Eli it is very very slow :(

Comment: I have implemented it. Its not working mostly all device above android M. is there any solution for it?

Comment: @MrNarendra Hi, It depends on a lot of factors (you can read the performance guide in the blog). If you still have problems, please email me, and I will try to assis you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes in android you can us ffmpeg4android for compress video it's native library

Please check this link

[ffmpeg4android Code](https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg)

**Install the Android NDK First to Use it**

Comment: Is NDK necessary for that? As I have seen sdk examples too.

Comment: Yes it's necessary because ffmpeg library build in C++ Code and c++ Code need their own compiler (Ndk) :)

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but in case it helps anyone else who reads this comment, FFmpeg4Android can run FFmpeg commands in Java without the need for C code, or installing the NDK. See this [link](http://androidwarzone.blogspot.com/2011/12/ffmpeg4android.html) for more info. At time of this comment, the page clearly states: "FFmpeg4Android is a way your application can run FFmpeg commands,  only Java, no need for C code, or NDK."