# How to compress large size video to small size in Android?

Tags: android, compression

Is it possible to compress a *large size video* to a *small size video* before uploading to any sever in `Android`?

How can it be done programmatically in java `Android`?

Comment: To compress a video, you will need to re-encode it to a lower bit-rate or maybe a lower resolution. For this see [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991863/is-it-possible-to-compress-video-on-android).