# In android device how can we compress video before upload Via Browser?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, android-browser

Is it possible to video compress before upload via browser?
Like in iOS devices, browse video using HTML input type file tag and iOS make compress before uploading.

Or any javascript or jQuery library helping for compress in Android device browser ??

Comment: To compress the video you need to re encode the video. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10991863/is-it-possible-to-compress-video-on-android)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to compress video is to re-encode it. You can encode with lower quality settings than the default video recorder, and decrease the resolution.

There are a few options for client-side encoding, but they are functionally limited.

[Whammy.js](http://antimatter15.com/wp/2012/08/whammy-a-real-time-javascript-webm-encoder/)
Encodes webm, but currently doesn't support audio. Bummer.

[Firefogg](http://firefogg.org/dev/)
Encodes webm and ogg. Only works in firefox.

Encoding is a cpu-intensive process. It will eat a ton of battery, and will take a while to process. If your goal is to save time on the upload, this probably won't help you much.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to Mohan reply. 
By using:

> [ffmpeg4android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netcompss.ffmpeg4android&feature=search_result)

However for the parameters, you may refer to

> [ffmpeg parameters](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Video-Conversion-With-FFMPEG.html)   (Do ignore the php codes)